# How to fix a z-index issue in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, z-index

I am designing [this landing](https://manualdeconfiguraciongoogletagmanager.elgatodiego.com/test/index.html) using Bootstrap and my own code. As you can see the main menu it's not showing all the content above the HTML. This is the [CSS](https://manualdeconfiguraciongoogletagmanager.elgatodiego.com/test/css/estilos-sitio.css).

How do I fix this issue? I think that it is a z-index problem. Am I right?

Here is the [original menu code](https://codepen.io/vulchivijay/pen/bEWqdP).

THANKS

Here is part of the css menu code:

```css
/*----------ESTILOS MENU -----------*/
  .menuBtn {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 10px;
    z-index: 101;
  }
  .menuBtn > span {
    background-color: var(--color-primario);
    height: var(--altura-linea);
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -1px 0 0 -15px;
    transition: height 100ms;
  }
  .menuBtn > span:after,
  .menuBtn > span:before {
    content: '';
    background-color: var(--color-primario);
    height: var(--altura-linea);
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -15px;
    transition: all 200ms;
  }
  .menuBtn > span:after {
    top: -7px;
  }
  .menuBtn > span:before {
    bottom: -7px;
  }
  .menuBtn.act > span {
    height: 0;
  }
  .menuBtn.act > span:after,
  .menuBtn.act > span:before {
    background-color: #008877;
    top: 1px;
  }
  .menuBtn.act > span:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .menuBtn.act > span:before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  /* main menu block */
  .mainMenu {
    background-color: var(--color-blanco);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  .mainMenu.act {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  .mainMenu.act ul li {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  .mainMenu ul {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .mainMenu li {
    padding: 8px 0;
    transition: all 400ms 510ms;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .mainMenu li:nth-child(odd) {
    transform: translateX(30%);
  }
  .mainMenu li:nth-child(even) {
    transform: translateX(-30%);
  }
  .mainMenu li:last-child {
    transform: none;
  }
  .mainMenu a {
    color: #19b698;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .mainMenu a.suBtn {
    color: var(--color-blanco);
  }

  .act{
    background-color: red;
  }
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to provide at least a representative sample of your HTML. Don't send us to other sites.

Comment: I'm also having a hard time understanding "not showing all the content above the HTML". Please explain better.

Comment: Very difficult to understand your descriptions, but want to confirm it.  you want this? http://prntscr.com/26gh7xb

Comment: I this picture (https://snipboard.io/8hXRQL.jpg) i am showing the issue, the idea is that the menu content (in red) should be above of the content (in green)

Comment: @DiegoDiaz, that's not z-index problem. currently header height is 50vh. please fix that first!!!

Comment: @RomanGavrilov what could be the issue?. Thanks

Comment: @diegodiaz  this is correct? http://prntscr.com/26ghe6u

Comment: @DiegoDiaz, in that image the menu _is_ above the green block. It just happens to stop where the green block starts. I still don't understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update @RomanGavrilov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please update your css like this

```
/*----------ESTILOS MENU -----------*/
      .menuBtn {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 20px;
        top: 10px;
        z-index: 101;
      }
      .menuBtn > span {
        background-color: var(--color-primario);
        height: var(--altura-linea);
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        margin: -1px 0 0 -15px;
        transition: height 100ms;
      }
      .menuBtn > span:after,
      .menuBtn > span:before {
        content: '';
        background-color: var(--color-primario);
        height: var(--altura-linea);
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -15px;
        transition: all 200ms;
      }
      .menuBtn > span:after {
        top: -7px;
      }
      .menuBtn > span:before {
        bottom: -7px;
      }
      .menuBtn.act > span {
        height: 0;
      }
      .menuBtn.act > span:after,
      .menuBtn.act > span:before {
        background-color: #008877;
        top: 1px;
      }
      .menuBtn.act > span:after {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
      }
      .menuBtn.act > span:before {
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
      }
      /* main menu block */
      .mainMenu {
        background-color: var(--color-blanco);
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 100;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
        text-align: center;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
        transform: scale(0);
      }
      .mainMenu.act {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1);
      }
      .mainMenu.act ul li {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
      .mainMenu ul {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
      .mainMenu li {
        padding: 8px 0;
        transition: all 400ms 510ms;
        opacity: 0;
      }
      .mainMenu li:nth-child(odd) {
        transform: translateX(30%);
      }
      .mainMenu li:nth-child(even) {
        transform: translateX(-30%);
      }
      .mainMenu li:last-child {
        transform: none;
      }
      .mainMenu a {
        color: #19b698;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 18px;
      }
      .mainMenu a.suBtn {
        color: var(--color-blanco);
      }
    
      .act{
        background-color: red;
      }
```

Comment: Please include some explanation of the changes, or inline documentation. Don't expect us to compare all that line-by-line. See [answer].